# Arduino IDE from php script: error

Tags: php, bash, arduino, raspberry-pi3, arduino-ide

I'm trying to run Arduino IDE (CLI) from php script using `shell_exec()` with my Raspberry Pi that works as server. The command that build and upload sketch is inside a bash script. When I run it with terminal locally, it works fine, but if I run it using Postman from client side, Arduino IDE gives me this error:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: 
Settings issues: Arduino cannot run because it could not
create a folder to store your settings.
```

Bash script:

```
#...arduino command 

/opt/arduino-1.8.3/arduino --board arduino:samd:mkr1000 --port /dev/ttyACM0 --upload /path/of/sketch/sketch.ino
```

Php script:

```
...
$command = './compileAndUpload.sh';
shell_exec($command);
...
```

I tried to modify `settings.path` from `preferences.txt` in Arduino folder thinking the problem was related permissions but it did not work.

Could someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps the user account that the PHP script runs under (web server user?) doesn't have the appropriate rights to create the directory? What does the web server error logs say?

Comment: Apache error.log gives the message:

"Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: 
Settings issues: Arduino cannot run because it could not
create a folder to store your settings."

Nothing else.